# Google maps for rails: How to normalize two address fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gmaps4rails

I am using the google maps for rails gem - https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails. According to there model customization guide here - https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Model-Customization I would like to normalize my address field. But aparently I have two address (`from and to`). How do I do it?

I tried this

```
  acts_as_gmappable :normalized_address => "from_address" && "to_address"

  def gmaps4rails_address
    from_address && to_address
  end
```

It doesnt work entirely. Only `to_address` gets normalized. `from_address` stays as it is entered by the user (Although it calculates it fine. But I would like to have the normalized version).

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with the models rather than gmaps4rails. You should have each address as a [polymorphic object](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations). Then attach twice to the parent model; once as from_address and once as to_address. Each address can then be normalized on it's own.

Edited with example....

Example:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :mappable, :polymorphic => true
  acts_as_gmappable :normalized_address => "address_string"

  def gmaps4rails_address
     address_string
  end
end

class YourMainModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :from_address, :as => :mappable
  has_one :to_address, :as => :mappable
end
```

Comment: hmm, if you dont mind could you give me an example? Right now its currently under the `Counter` model. And `to_address` and `from_address` are database fields. How exactly should I make polymorphic objects?. Sorry but i am fairly new to rails. An example from your side will really help a lot. thanks